# Sharing scope while dynamically resolving dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a situation where a class (`Parent`) has a dependency (`IScopedInstance`) and also resolves an other interface (`IOtherDependency`) dynamically inside a method. The implementation of that interface (`Dependency`) has the same dependency as the original class. I want that instance to be scoped to the instance of `Parent` ie: I want the same instance inside `Parent` and `Dependency`, but only if the dependency was resolved from inside `Parent` I'm using Castle.Windsor as DI-container.

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public Parent(IScopedInstance instance)
    {

    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var anotherDependency = container.Resolve<IOtherDependency>();
    }
}

public class Dependency : IOtherDependency
{
    public Dependency(IScopedInstance instance)
    {
    }
}
```

This works when `IOtherDepedency` is injected into the constructor of `Parent`:

```
container.Register(Component
            .For<IScopedInstance>()
            .ImplementedBy<ScopedInstance>()
            .LifestyleBoundTo(x => x.First(xx => 
                xx.ComponentModel.Implementation.InheritsOrImplements(typeof(IParent)))));
```

But understandably it doesn't work when resolving it from inside the method, since there's no `IParent` in the dependency graph (it's a new graph).

The real use case is a bit different and I don't directly resolve the `IOtherDependency` inside the method, but I removed all the extra info that's not needed.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shoul a factory, most likely a typed factory, within you method in order to get an instance from the container. 
I guess a scoped lifestyle should fit your needs, or a perwebrequest lifestyle if you code is running in a web app.

Comment: @ChristianoDegiorgis is right. You should register a factory method or a factory with [TypeFactorySelector](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to resolve your dependencies and push them through the constructor. 
Another down side of your implementation is that your class knows about the container and has a dependency on the container and its assembly.

Is there any obstacle that blocks you from using constructor injection via factories?

Comment: As I said, I don't directly resolve the dependency, but I do it through a factory, it's just not important here. I have a scoped lifestyle (see my last code snippet), it's just that inside method I need a dynamic dispatch. I'm using a generic interface which is reused in multiple places. The problem with the scoping is that there are two separate graphs, so the second does not have access to the scope of the first one